# How to download multiple xml files in Mono for Android without heap memory corruption?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 IDE and I am developing an Android application using C# and the Mono for Android framework.

My question is how would you properly request your application to download a bunch of files and store them on your device?

Currently, I am not able to download the needed 69 xml files (totalling about 6 MB), because it returns an "*ABORTING: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN tmalloc_large*" error. However, I have tested 30 files (about 3 MB) and it downloads them just fine and I am able to use them. I need all 69 files to run my application. Please help. Here are the methods I am using, please give corrections, additions, or alternative methods to use. I deeply appreciate it.

```
public void DownloadLanguagePack(string language, string[] files)
{            
    // Download each file inside the 'files' array
    for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] args = { language, files[i].FileName};

        // This way...
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new System.Uri(files[i].FileURL), args);
    }
}

void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = (string[])e.UserState;
    string language = args[0];
    string filename = args[1] + ".xml";

    if (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState == Android.OS.Environment.MediaMounted)
    {
        // Directory logic, works just fine
        var dir = new Java.IO.File(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
        var folder = new Java.IO.File(dir, language);
        var file = new Java.IO.File(folder, filename);
        if (!folder.Exists())
        {
            folder.Mkdirs();
        }

        // Tested with & without ThreadPool and makes no difference.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
        {
            // THIS IS THE AREA THAT I BELIEVE NEEDS SOME WORK, MAYBE NOT.
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            using (Stream s = e.Result)
            {
                // Load xml into document
                doc = XDocument.Load(s);

                using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file.Path, false))
                {
                    // Save document
                    doc.Save(stream);
                    stream.Flush();
                    stream.Close();

                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN tmalloc_large, ouch.  Looks like an Android or Mono bug to me.  What device are you testing on?

Comment: PS.  The using.. construct looks fine to me.  Under the covers, using just expands to a try-catch-finally.  However, the stream is disposable so I would lose the close and GC.Collect.

Comment: Just for testing, what happens if you move the XDocument doc declaration to the class level and simply new it each time in wc_OpenReadCompleted?

Comment: Greetings Simon. You're right about the using statements, I removed close and collect. However, I tried moving the XDocument to class level and still same error.